# AsynTask and Service binding

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-service, android-service-binding

This is a very silly one, and it's only because I don't like my code outputting errors to logcat that I'm asking about it.

I have a service called `BackgroundCollectorProcess`. It's main job, it to process rows in the database that haven't yet been reported. This is done via an XMPP connection. So, in `onStartCommand` I have the following:

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.d("BGCP", "Spinning");

        // Bind to our XmppConnector service to post any waiting transactions
        Intent iXmpp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackgroundXmppConnector.class);
        bindService(iXmpp, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);      

        // Start the sending of all collected logs
        new DeliveriesSenderTask().execute();
        new GeoLogSenderTask().execute();

        /*
            WARNING!!

            You can't call unbindService(mConnection) here - as the two main threads
            for posting delivery and geolocation transactions wont have completed in
            time. Thus, leaving this object unable to complete it's task.

            Logcat will throw up an "error" - saying about a resource binding being
            leaked in this class. 

            TODO: Revisit this once there is a definitive answer to the problem.
         */

        // Commit suicide. BackgroundCollectorKicker will ressurect me. 
        stopSelf();

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

As you can see by my massive wall of text for a comment, I've run into a stupid logcat error. Which is:

```
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078): Service com.goosesys.gaggle.services.BackgroundCollectorProcess has leaked ServiceConnection com.goosesys.gaggle.services.BackgroundCollectorProcess$1@449ddff0 that was originally bound here
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.goosesys.gaggle.services.BackgroundCollectorProcess has leaked ServiceConnection com.goosesys.gaggle.services.BackgroundCollectorProcess$1@449ddff0 that was originally bound here
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1507)
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1496)
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078):    at com.goosesys.gaggle.services.BackgroundCollectorProcess.onStartCommand(BackgroundCollectorProcess.java:70)
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2681)
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:146)
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1337)
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5171)
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
05-16 15:30:26.243: E/ActivityThread(16078):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

These are the AsyncTasks:

```
    private class DeliveriesSenderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
        {
            try
            {
                doPostDeliveries();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Utility.writeExceptionToLog(getApplicationContext(), ex);
            }           
            return null;
        }       
    }

    private class GeoLogSenderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {       
            try
            {
                doPostGeoLogs();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Utility.writeExceptionToLog(getApplicationContext(), ex);
            }
            return null;
        }       
    }
```

Now, given that the tasks to be run themselves, are (or can be) quite time consuming, they have to be run in separate threads. So, I can't then call `unbindService()`, because the threads haven't finished.

My question is... When is best to call `unbindService`? Obviously, I've attempted to call it once `GeoLogSenderTask` has completed, but I still get LogCat outputting this silly message, because the main thread will finish before the two asynctasks.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried calling it in `onPostExecute()` in one of your `AsyncTasks`?

Comment: Hi Andrew. Yup. That was one of the first things I tried, but because I kill the service with stopSelf, I still see the message because the thread finished before the final one. It's not detrimental to the apps performance, I just don't like having errors in LogCat that I'm responsible for :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save both asyncTask instances as member variables.
Introduce in both AsyncTask implementations the `onPostExecute` method and in both methods check if the other task has finished with `AsyncTask.getStatus == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED`.
When the other is finished call `stopSelf()` of the service.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
    if(otherTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
      stopSelf();
    }
  };
```